# Is Data protection capability sufficient for securize application files

Tags: xcode, encryption, swift3, cryptography, data-protection

I want to prevent modifications from my application files stored in Documents directory.

I try [CryptoSwift](https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift) and [AES256CBC](https://github.com/SwiftyBeaver/AES256CBC) libs but they greatly slow down my application which has multiple read / write files

Enabling [`Data Protection`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH26-SW30) capability on my application project it enough for prevent user to modifying theses files content ?

Comment: It is best to avoid using CryptoSwift, amoung other things it is 100 to 1000 times slower than Common Crypto based implementations. Apple's Common Crypto is FIPS certified and as such has been well vetted, using CryptoSwift is taking a chance on correctness and security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data protection feature is secure against everyone except the iPhone owner if the iPhone is not jailbroken. It uses AES encryption and the encryption key is stored in the keychain.

The data protection feature used Common Crypto that uses the hardware encryption engine and is very fast, on my iPhone 6s 1MB encrypts in ~2.3 mSec, a rate of > 400MB/s.

Comment: Is it then easy for the device owner to modify these files?

Comment: No it is not easy. But the device owner has full access to the same areas the developer does (more if the owner jailbreaks the device), if you need to protect against the device owner you need DRM, not just encryption. The issue is that if the encryption key is on the device the owner can get access. But there is an increase in work factor and that raised the level of capabilities needed to access the data.

Comment: First I want to discourage adventurous user to modify theses sensitives datas, I will stay on this solution to privilege the user experience of my application. Thank you for the clarification !

Comment: @Khorwin Anything your application can decrypt on the user's device, a user can decrypt by decompiling, debugging, and reverse engineering your code. There's little workaround for that. To have truly secure DRM systems, you need dedicated hardware on the device that can enforce your DRM policy without any possible user intervention. HDCP is an example of this.

Comment: @Alexander, I understand that I would not have something completely secure. My application will be used in a specific domain (users under contracts) and I just have to prove to the competent authority in this domain that users will not have write access to the data stored on the device. I do not try to hide sensitive data but prevent a user from "cheating" easily

Comment: @Khorwin are you sure this can't be implemented with a server, to which the client can delegate the "privileged" actions? The server could then enforce the security policy you wish to have.

Comment: @Alexander There is the issue of who needs to be protected against and finding a work factor that matches that. Sometimes simple protections are enough, sometimes hardware security is needed and there is the in between needs. The designer needs to determine the cost/benefit needs.

Comment: @zaph Indeed. I didn't convey my intent well in my last comment. It was meant to be a proposition for OP to consider, should they need a high level of security

Comment: @Alexander I agree. But anyone asking here is in general going to be abe to put together a high security system. I have a friend who does high level security, 10 years of full time supervised work before working un-supervised.